# How Can i pass multiple parameter dynamically get request to check whether fbtoken is valid or not

Tags: php, facebook

This is What i want

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=EAACYdONPWL0BAMNrFjZB59DWZB3FwEQKexzD5efTjYoSIDzfpUNfFJKGqouUZBdZBD4PPb7qeoPXqbJGnBBfbh7DhYuGN7hZAfU2UYhZBZA32CJFqP5DmbzZA8qdKvQ9U4eXTwUke7QKcMtd5V5EBI2SyYsKtMHjkUZAuKD1AtAcMZBcNRa5zMaoDufN4lPET8nTScMHzleadxLjXLqt6Nx1c2TjwmNRJKZBNkBegqgZDZD&access_token=c6e0ab918b974aea2a6a6a800c34
```

and i am doing like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=$fb_token&access_token=$access_token
```

The Response coming  in curl is
"Illegal characters found in URL"

As i am new in php i will be very thankful

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve]. _“and i am doing like this”_ - we don’t know the context of this, and in the form you have shown this isn’t even PHP code (at least not necessarily, it could still be plain text.) Anyway, with _any_ value you introduce into the query string of a URL, you should use `urlencode` to begin with.

Comment: there's no curl here or php, it's just urls with some variables

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i didn't add that because those are working fine i have issue in passing  multiple paramters dynamically

Comment: that makes your post unclear, to which I voted to close as. You can try what @CBroe wrote at the end of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get that error because you are not properly urlencoding the variables you insert into the url. use urlencode() or http_build_query(), eg

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?' . http_build_query ( array (
        'input_token' => $fb_token,
        'access_token' => $access_token 
) );
```

or

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=' . urlencode ( $fb_token ) . "&access_token=" . urlencode ( $access_token );
```

and it will be properly urlencoded.